# Render server side JSON in Django REST Framework

Tags: json, django, request, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make bulk data downloads by serializing my entire database as JSON. The [drf documentation on serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects) has a section that says you can simply do:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment)
json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for HyperLinked relationships. When you try to do it with them, you get something like:

> AssertionError: `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.

So, I figured out I can add context attribute, like:

```
r = Request(request=HttpRequest())
context = dict(request=r)
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, context=context)
json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

Which then returns the error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "opinioncluster-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

I know this API works properly when it's called from the browser, but I can't get past this when I call it as above. Something that's automatic from the browser doesn't happen when you render it manually.

Any ideas?

---

#### First edit

Here's another strategy that seemed promising because it would add the path to my request object:

```
r = Request(request=RequestFactory().get(reverse('comment-list', kwargs={'version': 'v3'})))
context = dict(request=r)
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, context=context)
json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

That returns the same problem as if I hadn't defined a path to the request:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "opinioncluster-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

#### Second Edit

As I said in my comments, I'm fairly certain my serializers and views aren't to blame, since they work perfectly fine via the browser. Nevertheless, here they are. If you're truly generous, the full serializers, filters, and codebase [is online](https://github.com/freelawproject/courtlistener/tree/opinion-split/cl/search).

**View**:

```
class OpinionClusterViewSet(LoggingMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = OpinionCluster.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OpinionClusterSerializer
    filter_class = OpinionClusterFilter
    ordering_fields = (
        'date_created', 'date_modified', 'date_filed', 'citation_count',
        'date_blocked',
    )
```

**Serializer**:

```
class OpinionClusterSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer,
                               serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    absolute_url = serializers.CharField(source='get_absolute_url',
                                         read_only=True)
    panel = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        view_name='judge-detail',
        read_only=True,
    )
    non_participating_judges = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        view_name='judge-detail',
        read_only=True,
    )
    docket = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=False,
        view_name='docket-detail',
        read_only=True,
    )

    sub_opinions = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        view_name='opinion-detail',
        read_only=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = OpinionCluster
```

Comment: Are you doing your export via a custom Django's management command, or just in a "standalone" script? I mean, do you have Django loaded and initialized before you start `render()`ing?

Comment: It's a management command.

Comment: Try supplying a real path to your `HttpRequest()` constructor. My first guess is that Django fails to determine the app namespace or something.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexMorozov. I tried that too....still same problem.

Comment: What is the view name for the field on the `CommentSerializer`? You didn't include the serializer code here, so I can really only guess that you actually have an issue there. Usually this is because you either didn't add it to the router (are you using a router? want to include that snippet?) or because you are using a namespace within your API.

Comment: @KevinBrown, I can put the view, serializer and everything else in place, but I'm fairly certain that's not it because it works perfectly well via the browser or curl.

Comment: @KevinBrown I put the view and serializer in as Edit 2. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging quite deeply into the code, I finally figured this out:

```
r = RequestFactory().request()
r.version = 'v3'
r.versioning_scheme = URLPathVersioning()
context = dict(request=r)
renderer = JSONRenderer()
json_str = renderer.render(
    serializer(item, context=context).data,
    accepted_media_type='application/json; indent=2',
)
```

This seems to work, but the HyperLinkRelated values in the JSON that is serialized have the server set to `testserver`. I could get around that by setting:

```
r.META['SERVER_NAME']
```

But I also need to set `r.scheme` to `https`, which doesn't seem to be possible (I get an error that `r.scheme` cannot be set).

I'm pretty close though, so this is going to have to serve as an answer for now.

Comment: Cross-linking to the "Allow mocking of Requests" issue... https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3825

Answer (score 0):

This management command creates a `MockRequest` to be used in a non-browser environment and should allow you to create your JSON:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.http import HttpRequest

from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.request import Request

from comments.models import Comment
from comments.serializers import CommentSerializer


class MockRequest(HttpRequest):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MockRequest, self).__init__()
        self.setup_host()

    def setup_host(self):
        # Required to give absolute urls in output
        self.META['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost:8000'  


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Export JSON'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        request = MockRequest()

        serializer_context = {
            'request': Request(request),
        }

        comment = Comment.objects.first()

        serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, context=serializer_context)
        json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)

        print(json)
```

To remove the hard coded domain you could use the `Sites` framework to power the host name:

```
def setup_host(self):
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
    site = Site.objects.get_current()
    self.META['HTTP_HOST'] = site.domain
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, @Ashley. I put it in place, but I still get the same error about `Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship...`